# Un programa simple en C++ se traba en la tercera variable

Tags: c++

Trato de crear un programa en *C++* para calcular una ganancia con ciertos *impuestos*, y por algún motivo el programa se rompe cuando lee la tercera variable. ¿Cómo soluciono este inconveniente?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int NG, PG, PCe, Ganancia;

int main ()
{
    printf("Digite la cantidad que tiene: \n");
    scanf("%s", &NG);
    printf("Digite a que precio esta: \n");
    scanf("%s", &PG);
    printf("Digita a que precio esta cada unidad del producido: \n");
    scanf("%s", &PCe);
    Ganancia=((NG*5)*PC)-((NG*500)+(NG*PG));
    printf("Se tienen :\n\n\t %s unidades\n\n\t",NG);
    printf("El precio es: %s \n\n\t",PG);
    printf("Y el precio de la unidad de producido es: %s \n\n\t",PCe); 
    printf("Por lo que la ganancia sera de: %s",Ganancia);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que el código es C++?

Answer (score 3):

> Por algún motivo el programa se rompe cuando lee la tercera variable.

Lo raro es que funcione incluso con la primera. Estás usando `scanf` (que es una utilidad de las librerías de [c](/questions/tagged/c), no de [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)) leyendo en valores de tipo entero (`int`) valores de tipo cadena (`%s`):

```
int NG, PG, PCe, Ganancia;

int main ()
{
    //          vvv <-- variable int
    scanf("%s", &NG);
    //     ~~ <--- leer cadena

    //          vvv <-- variable int
    scanf("%s", &PG);
    //     ~~ <--- leer cadena

    //          vvv <-- variable int
    scanf("%s", &PCe);
    //     ~~ <--- leer cadena
```

Lo mismo te pasa al escribir con `printf`. Si lo que esperas es leer/escribir un número [debes usar la marca `%d`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf):

```
int NG, PG, PCe, Ganancia;

int main ()
{
    //          vvv <-- variable int
    scanf("%d", &NG);
    //     ~~ <--- leer numero

    //          vvv <-- variable int
    scanf("%d", &PG);
    //     ~~ <--- leer numero

    //          vvv <-- variable int
    scanf("%d", &PCe);
    //     ~~ <--- leer numero
```

Pero mejor aún, deja de usar cabeceras de C y ya que has etiquetado la pregunta como C++, úsalo:

```
#include <iostream>

int NG, PG, PCe, Ganancia;

int main ()
{
    std::cout << "Digite la cantidad que tiene: \n";
    std::cin >> NG;

    std::cout << "Digite a que precio esta: \n";
    std::cin >> PG;

    std::cout << "Digita a que precio esta cada unidad del producido: \n";
    std::cin >> PCe;

    Ganancia=((NG*5)*PC)-((NG*500)+(NG*PG));
    std::cout << "Se tienen :\n\n\t" << NG << " unidades\n\n\t"
              << "El precio es: " <<  PG << "\n\n\t"
              << "Y el precio de la unidad de producido es: " << PCe << "\n\n\t"
              << "Por lo que la ganancia sera de: " <<  Ganancia;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes varios avisos en tu código, que no suponen un error en sí.

En primer lugar, '%s' espera un argumento del tipo 'char*', pero le pasas un 'int*'.

Lo que sí es un error es que empleas PC sin haber declarado la variable; entiendo que es PG. Y si no lo es, tienes que sustituir por la que sea, por ejemplo PCe que es en la que dices que se traba. No es que se "trabe", sino que está mal escrita.

Te muestro el código compilado correctamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el código por aquí:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int NG, PG, PCe, Ganancia;

int main ()
{
    printf("Digite la cantidad que tiene: \n");
    scanf("%d", &NG);
    printf("Digite a que precio esta: \n");
    scanf("%d", &PG);
    printf("Digita a que precio esta cada unidad del producido: \n");
    scanf("%d", &PCe);
    Ganancia=((NG*5)*PG)-((NG*500)+(NG*PG));
    printf("Se tienen :\n\n\t %d unidades\n\n\t",NG);
    printf("El precio es: %d \n\n\t",PG);
    printf("Y el precio de la unidad de producido es: %d \n\n\t",PCe);
    printf("Por lo que la ganancia sera de: %d",Ganancia);
    return 0;
}
```

No entro a valorar si está mejor o peor el código en sí, pero de esta forma no te da ningún error. Eso sí,  sí el código es c++ deberías utilizarlo, porque tal y como lo tienes utilizas C.

Para que veas el aspecto del programa que has hecho corriendo, te agrego otra captura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]